# Zend Framework 2, making the model query a web service

Tags: php, web-services, rest, model-view-controller, zend-framework2

I'm completely new to Zend framework (though I've already used Symfony2 and I've heard they're similar), and I've started a project in which I have to upgrade a site (that is already fully functional) that was created with Zend 1.11.

The aim of my upgrade is to allow data (that was originally stored in a database, and that will now be stored in nosql, and a database, and could be in the future stored elsewhere) to be more buildable and less strongly coupled with Zend's model. (Model as in the M of MVC).

[image: project]

In order to achieve this, I was asked to use a web service that would interact with the data, and Zend's model.
That way, when the data's structure would be modified, the Zend website wouldn't directly be impacted, (and would still work!) and we'd just have to re-arrange the web service.

Is there any elegant way to make Zend's model interact with a web service rather than a database?

I hope my question is understandable...

Have a nice day,

M.G.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Data mapper pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html). As a reference, you can see how the module [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser) has [adopted this pattern](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/1.x/src/ZfcUser/Mapper/UserInterface.php)

You can create an interface of mapper for each entity and create an implementation according to the the data storage.
For example,

**Product Entity**

```
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;


    /**
     * Get id.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set id.
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @return UserInterface
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = (int) $id;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set name.
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return UserInterface
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }       
}
```

**Product Mapper**

```
<?php

<?php
namespace Product\Mapper;

interface ProductMapperInterface
{
    /**
     * @var int $id
     * @returns \Product\Entity\Product
     */ 
    public function findById($id);

    /**
     * @var array $criteria
     * @returns \Product\Entity\Product[]
     */ 
    public function find(array $criteria, .....);

    /**
     * @var \Product\Entity\Product $product
     */ 
    public function insert($product);

    /**
     * @var \Product\Entity\Product $product
     */     
    public function update($product);
}
```

To populate the entity, you can use [hydrators](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.stdlib.hydrator.html). As a reference, you can view how ZfcUser uses [hydrators](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/1.x/src/ZfcUser/Mapper/UserHydrator.php).

Comment: I'm sorry but I forgot to say the site was made with Zend version 1.11. What I've tried doing is change all my model classes that extended Zend_Db_Table_Abstract into "classic" classes (like your first example of code). Then I'm planning to use another class, "sendRestRequest" that would manage the communication with the web service (and therefore create entities of each "classic" model class). Do you think this is a good idea or is there a better way to achieve my goal which is making this Zend website work thanks to a webservice and not thanks to the database...

Comment: It does not mapper which version of zend you are using if you want to use this pattern. You need to make sure that all other classes only depend on MapperInterface to fetch and manipulate data. Create a class implementing MapperInterface (example WebServiceStorageMapper) and inside that you include the logic to manage the communication with the web service. To reduce redundancy you can create a class like `WebServiceStorage`(or `sendRestRequest`) and all the mappers which use web service will depend on WebServiceStorage.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, I will try this out (for the moment I'm not sure I have understood everything) and come back here if I have more questions :p

Comment: sorry. there is a typo in my last comment.
"It does not matter which version of zend you are using if you want to use this pattern."